# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support CREATE_PARTITIONS

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When I start my spring cloud stream application which contains kafka, I got this error, what does it means and how to resolve this problem?

ps : I have another project using the same middleware kafka and it can work correctly.

this is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.gyfg.zttest</groupId>
    <artifactId>zttest-stream-task</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>zttest-stream-task</name>
    <description>zttestproject for stream listener</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.gyfg</groupId>
        <artifactId>zttest</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.gyfg.zttest.streamtask.TypeConversionApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>zttest-stream-task</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <configuration> <classifier>exec</classifier> </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
    </build>

</project>
```

this is my application.yml :

```
server:
  port: 8082
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring:
  application:
    name: zttest-stream-task
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
          consumer:
            concurrency: 3
            resetOffsets: true
            auto:
              offset:
                reset: latest
      bindings:
        syslogin_channel:
          destination: SysLog
          group: SysLog
        businesslogin_channel:
          destination: BusinessLog
          group: BusinessLog
      kafka:
          binder:
              zk-nodes: localhost:2181
              brokers:  localhost:9092
              autoAddPartitions: true
              resetOffsets: true
              startOffset: latest
  redis:
    database: 3
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
    password: 
    timeout: 10000
```

`Kafka version : 1.1.0` this can be found in my eclipse console.

Comment: Not clear what version of Kafka you are using in the client or running on the broker

Comment: @cricket_007 oh, I'm sorry that I forgot, this is found in my eclipse console [ Kafka version : 1.1.0 ]

Comment: @cricket_007 it's so ashamed, i just found my kafka server version is  kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1 , and my client viersion is  Kafka version : 1.1.0  , my server version is too low, I need to upgrade my server version

Comment: That sounds more involved that just downgrading the client.